# How to select points that are outside a buffer in R?

Tags: r, buffer, shapefile, r-sf

I am using a point dataset of class `sf` and a road network of class `sf`. I created a buffer with the road network using the `st_buffer()` function and I can successfully select the points that are within the roads by using the following:
`points_within_roads <- st_intersection(points_shp, roads_buffer)`

I need to do the opposite. I want to select the points that are outside the roads. Is there a function that allows me to do that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the `sf::st_disjoint` function. For example:

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

# create some fake data
set.seed(1234)
my_line <- st_linestring(rbind(c(-1, -1), c(1, 1)))
my_points <- st_cast(st_sfc(st_multipoint(matrix(runif(100, -1, 1), ncol = 2))), "POINT")
my_buffer <- st_buffer(my_line, 0.1)

# plot 
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(st_boundary(my_buffer), col = "darkgrey")
plot(my_line, add = TRUE)
plot(my_points[my_buffer, op = st_intersects], add = TRUE, col = "darkred")
plot(my_points[my_buffer, op = st_disjoint], add = TRUE, col = "darkblue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Moreover, I think you misspelt `sf::st_intersection` where it should be `sf::st_intersects`.

Comment: I actually used `st_intersection`. It works better than `st_intersect`. If I chose multiple roads, `st_intersect` get me points that are incorrect.

Comment: Well, but they are two different functions. `st_intersects` is used to identify if two geometries share any space while `st_intersection` creates a new geometry for the shared portion of space.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/sf.pdf) is a useful cheatsheet for several `sf` functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I need to convert the shapefiles into objects of class "sfg". When I use `st_disjoint`, I get an object of class `sgbp`. It doesn't seem like its doing anything. I get a large sgbp object with all points.

Comment: You should use the `sgbp` object for filtering the POINTS object. Check again my code and the syntax there. For example, if `p` is the `sf` object of POINTS and `b` is the `sf` object of raster, you should run `p[b, op = st_disjoint]`. If you want, you may also read the Chapters 2/3/4/5 of the following book: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, `p[b, op = st_disjoint]`, where `p` is the shapefile with the points, and `b` is the shapefile with the roads buffer and it's not doing anything. I'm getting an object with the exact total of points as in `p`. Both `p` and `b` are objects of class `"sf" "data.frame"` Is there something that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212883/discussion-between-agila-and-a-quinones).

Answer (score 0):

Could use of ! answer this question? Below is assuming you have an unique identifier column of some sort (ID).

```
points_outside_buffer <- filter(points_shp, !points_within_roads$ID %in% points_shp$ID)
```

I just did the below with some data I am working on and it worked fine

```
too_far <- filter(stations_sf_r, !stations_sf_r$StationCode %in% repeats$StationCode)
```